# Google indexed a page that doesn't exist

Tags: search-engine, google-search

There is something very weird happening on a website I'm working with. When I do a research on Google about a product of the website, the return result is a page that doesn't exist but it doesn't return a 404 error.

The "page.html" does exist, but it is not on the path that Google found, the URL is somehow being created out of nowhere, and since it is inside Joomla, it is causing some visual errors.

I've done some research, and a-lot of people have this kind of error, but normally the page is a 404 or a duplicated version. In my case, the page opens normally, the only thing is that the "page.html" is somehow being put on a path that is not correct. I've already checked inside the folders and there is not a duplicated page inside them.

What could be happening?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question with just the information given.  What is the expected full URL for `page.html` and what is the actual odd URL where its contents are appearing?  Please [edit] your question to add missing information

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow.  Please [edit] the question to address the points that need to be clarified, then re-ask it on [webmasters.se] and delete it here.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a website you host, you can mark the page as a `nofollow`. If not, Google Search has a beta feature called "About this Result" in which you can leave feedback telling Google the page does not exist. Also, if you reach a 404 page, Web Crawlers will find it on their own eventually.